# css position:relative div problem

Tags: html, css

this is part of my code:

css :

```
.body .left, .right {
       position:relative;
       z-index:6;
       display:inline-block;
}
.body .left {
       top:0;
       left:0;
       width:100px;
       height:300px;
       margin-right:10px;
       border:1px solid #333;
}
.body .right {
       top:0;
       width:100px;
       height:300px;
       border:1px solid #333;
}
```

and html

```
<div class="body">
    <div class="left">
    </div>
    <div class="right">
    </div>
</div>
```

i want them to be in one line `top:0;`,when there is no data added to `.left` or `.right` `div` it works good,  but the problem is that when i add text or something else to `.left` or `.right` `div` divs are arranged different, see example on jsfille to understand  about what i'm talking.

**View Example :** [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zct6S/7/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.body .left, .body .right {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

add the explicit vertical-alignment you want the inline-blocks to have;

#### [Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/HxejQ/)

```
.body .left, .body .right {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width:100px;
    height:300px;
    border:1px solid #333;
}
.body .left {
       margin-right:10px;
}
.body .right {}
```

If you want support for IE6/7 for your code you should add:

```
.body .left, .body .right {
   display: inline !ie7;
}
```

that `!ie7` is a hack, if you'd prefer not to use - just make sure those 2 classes get the value `display: inline` via a conditional comment .. whatever your preference ;)

HTML:

```
<div class="body">
    <div class="left">
        text
    </div>
    <div class="right">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you're welcome, I've updated the code and fiddle to remove all the unnecessary positioning now too, also if you need this to work in IE7 and below you will need to add : `.body .left, .body .right { display: inline !ie7;}` - or give IE6/7 the `display:inline;` property via a conditional comment or class

Answer (score 4):

Just replace your `.body .left, .right` `display: inline-block` with `float: left` and everything should work like you want.
Have a look: http://jsfiddle.net/Zct6S/10/

I also removed your `position: relative` as you don't need them if you use float.

Comment: If that's the case please post your example in context of your other divs.

Comment: i resolved the problem now by adding vertical-align:top, anyway thanks for the answer